# My icons look fine on desktop and dev-tools, but are smushed once on an iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, reactjs

My footer icons are smushed vertically on ios. Once i rotate the phone they're fine, I've checked the aspect ratio and such on my browser dev tools and it works fine...just not on ios in vertical view. Again, they look fine when I rotate the phone, just not in vertical.

Any idea why this would be? I'm assuming it is in one of my media queries, I'll include a couple that could possibly be of concern.

I would seriously appreciate your help if you have some to offer!

I've tried using the XCode dev tools to spot the issue, didn't solve anything.

```
// Parent to imgLink

const SocialDiv = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;    
    align-self: flex-end;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
        width: 250px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:497px) {
        width:100%;
    }
`

// Child to Social Div

const imgLink = styled.a`
    height: 100%
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;   
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    align-self: center;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 525px) {
        width: 15%;
        margin: -3%;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:497px) {
          width: 25%;
          justify-content: center;
          margin: 0;
      } 
`
// Child to imgLink

const Img = styled.img`
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
`
```

The expected outcome is a 1x1 aspect ratio, right now i'm getting about 2:1 horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I had height: 100% where I definitely should have had a fixed amount. Fixed my issue!

For anyone reading this in the future, just make sure you have a media query specifically for the phone size.